# Pass OneToMany filed to NEW-Statement constructor

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I have got the following classes

```
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "User.FindByFilter", query = "SELECT NEW myPkg.SimpleUser(u.name , u.email, u.roles) FROM User u WHERE UPPER(u.name) LIKE :filter AND  ORDER BY u.name")
 })
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User implements Serializable, UserDetails {
    @Id
    private String email;
    @Basic
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.PERSIST }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Authority> roles;
...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Authority implements GrantedAuthority {
//just @Id and @Basic here no specific mapping back to user
...
}
```

Of course I know that this query

```
@NamedQuery(name = "User.FindByFilter", query = "SELECT NEW myPkg.SimpleUser(u.name , u.email, u.roles) FROM User u WHERE UPPER(u.name) LIKE :filter AND  ORDER BY u.name")
```

is wrong, because `u.roles` is `@OneToMany`.
So my question is what is the correct way to pass the roles field to the const.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [JPA 2.0 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) , it uses `single_valued_object_field` and `collection_valued_field` to represent a single entity field and collection entity field respectively :

> A **single_valued_object_field** is designated by the name of an
>   association field in a **one-to-one** or **many-to-one** relationship or a
>   field of  embeddable class type. The type of a
>   single_valued_object_field is the abstract schema type of the related
>   entity or embeddable class.
>
> A **collection_valued_field**  is designated by the name of an association
>   field in a **one-to-many** or a **many-to-many** relationship or by the name
>   of  an element collection field. The type of a collection_valued_field
>   is a collection of values of the abstract schema type of the related
>   entity or element type.

Then it defines the SELECT clause has the following syntax:

> - constructor_expression ::= NEW constructor_name ( constructor_item {, constructor_item}* )
> - constructor_item ::= single_valued_path_expression | scalar_expression | aggregate_expression | identification_variable

As `constructor_item` can accept `single_valued_path_expression` but not `collection_valued_field` , I don't think `new()` can accept the collection field parameter.

You have to use the fetch join to retrieve `User` instance together with its  `Authority` collection and then manually transform it to `myPkg.SimpleUser`

Comment: I did not find out anything else. My workaround is to make `SimpleUser` an entity that uses the same tabe and query `SimpleUser` objects directly.